# How to return term scores in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I get the term vector for an indexed document in elasticsearch?

That is, once I have uploaded several documents to my elasticsearch index, I would like to get the scored term vectors back so that I can see which which terms are over indexed for a given document and thus for a document show the most influential terms.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the Term Vectors API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html

Say you already indexed several documents. Then it's possible to get the term vectors using the following API call:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/<id>/_termvectors?pretty=true'
```

Just replace <id> with the id of the document you want create the query for.